# List of images is displayed wrong when a link is used around img

Tags: html, css, list, image, css-float

I would like to have a list of images floated in left and placed in div containers. Code based on W3 web. Here is the [illustrative Example](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_architect&stacked=h).

There are images with title on the Projects section. Is it possible to put a `href` link around these images to display properly?

I have tried it but it does not work, it is displayed strangely. As if the link caused that the positioning is wrongly calculated. Any idea?

[image: screenshot]

Please notice the `a` element with different image source, it causes the problem with positioning of images, different dimension?

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.w3-content {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.w3-border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.w3-container {
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.w3-padding-16 {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.w3-border-light-grey {
  border-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.w3-padding {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.w3-margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.w3-row-padding,
.w3-row-padding>.w3-col {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.w3-row-padding::before,
.w3-row-padding::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.w3-col {
  float: left;
  /* position: relative; */
}

.w3-col.w3-l3 {
  width: 24.9999999%;
}

.w3-display-topleft {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.w3-black {
  background: #000;
  color: white;
}

.w3-container-img {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-padding" style="max-width: 1564px">
  <div class="w3-container w3-padding-16">
    <h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-padding-16 w3-border-light-grey">Photos</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">
      <div class="w3-container-img">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding w3-black">Nature tour</div>
        <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1635417310384-4a7d54255edd?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1635417310384-4a7d54255edd?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80" style="width:100%">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">
      <div class="w3-container-img">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding w3-black">Nature tour</div>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/house5.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">
      <div class="w3-container-img">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding w3-black">Nature tour</div>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/house5.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">
      <div class="w3-container-img">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding w3-black">Nature tour</div>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/house5.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">
      <div class="w3-container-img">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding w3-black">Nature tour</div>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/house5.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">
      <div class="w3-container-img">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding w3-black">Nature tour</div>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/house5.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">
      <div class="w3-container-img">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding w3-black">Nature tour</div>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/house5.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">
      <div class="w3-container-img">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding w3-black">Nature tour</div>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/house5.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Mention what you need to be helped with.

Comment: Try adding `display:block;` to your `a` tag

Comment: Code added. The block did not help. Thanks for helping

Comment: Is there any reason not to fix the height of all the images? `img{max-height: 79px}`  is one way you could do that.

Comment: I have tried it and it worked :) Unfortunately it doesnt work when you try to zoom in/out your screen. The list images is again displayed wrongly. But many thanks for tip. It worked when I use only height: attribute.

Comment: However, I wonder what is good approach or practice for this problem. Is better to use the images with the same height or just use the attribute height? The first approach (same height of images) cannot cover images every time. Some of images have different dimension and always cropping images is not preferrable way I guess.

Answer (score 0):

#### Theoretical preface

Floating elements remain in the same row if they are of the same height. If one element protrudes slightly in height, the next row will catch on the protruding corner and an unoccupied space on the screen is formed.

#### Debugging

1. If we replace the first image by the second one, all images will be the same. The only difference will be the `a` tag around the first image. But the bug disappeared. So the problem places not in `a` tag.
2. Restore the original first image and remove the `a` tag. The bug remains. So we should research with images not with the `a` tag.
3. The first image has original sizes of `2070 × 1380 px`. All others are `500 × 333 px`. But which sizes have they in our layout?
4. Open developer tools in a browser. For example, click in Chrome with the right mouse on the image and select "Inspect". Hover over an `img` tag in the "Elements" panel and see what size the browser is showing on the screen. Aha! On my screen the first picture occupies `145 × 96.66 px`, and all the additional ones are `145 × 96.56 px`. Thus, the first picture is `0.1 px` higher. Reason found (see theoretical preface).

[image: see the reason]

#### Solution 1

You can wrap every 4 images in separate `div` block with the `w3-row-padding` class to make 2 independent rows.

```html
<div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
</div>
<div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
</div>
```

#### Solution 2

Or you can add an invisible separator after every fourth image. For example, Bootstrap 3 uses [the `.clearfix` class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#helper-classes-clearfix) for this.

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-l3 w3-margin-bottom">...</div>
</div>
```

#### Solution 3

Pre-process all images so that they have the same dimensions. Then, when decreasing, they will occupy the same area on the screen.

#### Solution 4

Change a layout. I prefer to show images as a backgrounds of the blocks with CSS properties:

```css
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

In this case, I am sure that the aspect ratio of the images does not affect the size of the blocks.